# Schedule task in sql express edition using batch file

Tags: sql, sql-server, windows, batch-file, sql-scripts

Requirements - Schedule task in SQL Express Edition.

But SQL server Agent functionality is not available in express edition.

Possible Solution- Schedule batch file execution to execute sql script. Tried

Batch File-`cmd /k  sqlcmd -i backup.sql`

Sql Script-`backup database DB_user1212 to disk = 'E:\backups\MyBackup.bak'`. But error occurred while executing sql script `A network related or instance specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server`

Possible Reason- Something like connection string missing. Help me how to solve this, i am using windows authentication for connection.

Comment: You're missing `-S server` and `-E` for trusted connection

Comment: Can you please give script to do above task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is add the additional parameters to your call to sqlcmd.

```
 sqlcmd -S yoursqlserver -E -i C:\pathto\backup.sql
```